# OSDev - Error when using the 'make' command in 'docker'

Tags: c, linux, docker, osdev

I started writing an OS kernel using the tutorial in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkrpUaGThTQ). I've already written the `Makefile` as you can see here:

```
x86_64_asm_source_files := $(shell find src/impl/x86_64 -name *.asm)  # Holds the list of all of the assembly source files.
x86_64_asm_object_files := $(patsubst src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, build/x86_64/%.o, $(x86_64_asm_source_files))  # Holds the list of all of the obj files.

# Define the command we need to run to build one of the object files from the source files:
$(x86_64_asm_object_files): build/x86_64/%.o : src/impl/x86_64/%.asm
# For compiling the assembly files:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && \
    nasm -f elf64 $(patsubst build/x86_64/%.o, src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, $@) -o $@

# Create a custom phony command:
.PHONY: build-x86_64

# Run only if any of the object files have been changed:
build-x86_64: $(x86_64_asm_object_files)
# For generating the '.iso' file:
    mkdir -p dist/x86_64 && \
    x86_64-elf-ld -n -o dist/x86_64/kernel.bin -T targets/x86_64/linker.ld $(x86_64_asm_object_files) && \
    cp dist/x86_64/kernel.bin targets/x86_64/iso/boot/kernel.bin && \
    grub-mkrescue /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc -o dist/x86_64/kernel.iso targets/x86_64/iso
```

When I run `make build-x86_64` inside a docker container, I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build-x86_64'.  Stop.
```

When I write the `make` command only it seems that there is no `makefile` due to this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

When I use the `make` command outside of docker, I get:

```
mkdir -p build/x86_64/boot/ && \
nasm -f elf64  src/impl/x86_64/boot/main.asm -o build/x86_64/boot/main.o
mkdir -p build/x86_64/boot/ && \
nasm -f elf64  src/impl/x86_64/boot/header.asm -o build/x86_64/boot/header.o
mkdir -p dist/x86_64 && \
x86_64-elf-ld -n -o dist/x86_64/kernel.bin -T targets/x86_64/linker.ld  build/x86_64/boot/main.o  build/x86_64/boot/header.o   && \
cp dist/x86_64/kernel.bin targets/x86_64/iso/boot/kernel.bin && \
grub-mkrescue /use/lib/grub/i386-pc -o dist/x86_64/kernel.iso targets/x86_64/iso
/bin/sh: 2: x86_64-elf-ld: not found
make: *** [Makefile:16: build-x86_64] Error 127
```

The docker command I use for building the docker itself is: `sudo docker build buildenv -t learnos-buildenv`

The docker command I use for running the docker terminal is: `sudo docker run --rm -it -v /root/env learnos-buildenv`

Is there anything I can do to fix `docker`? Or how can I get the `x86_64-elf-ld` compiler without using `docker`?

(My development OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.)

Comment: You have a typo. The target is called `build-x86_64` and not `build-x86-64`.

Comment: Thank you! But even then I steal have the same issue.

Comment: does it work outside docker?

Comment: I tried it outside of docker and I had problem with the compiler:
`
`nasm -f elf64  src/impl/x86_64/boot/header.asm -o build/x86_64/boot/header.o`
`/bin/sh: 2: x86_64-elf-ld: not found`
`make: *** [Makefile:16: build-x86_64] Error 127`

Comment: but was the target found? If the make was working outside docker, then make sure that inside the docker, make is called from the correct folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be at the directory of the project itself. If so, that's where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything did work when I used in the `makefile` the `ld` command instead of the `x86_64-elf-ld` command, and also I didn't use `docker` to compile my project.
If there is any better solution that includes compiling the files from `docker`, please write to me.

Thanks!